How to find the whether the detected object is in Horizontal or vertical position and measure the lenth in CV (using YOLO)
I am new to Computer Vision and have successfully detected an object in an image. Now, I need to determine whether the detected object is positioned horizontally or vertically, and I also need to measure the distance. Using height and width for measurement is not feasible because some images are zoomed in and others are not. Despite extensive searching, I haven't found a clear solution. Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to determine the orientation of a detected object in an image and measure the distance accurately? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Note: The photos are taken from different angles and distances


"an object"? do you realize that distances/sizes cannot be measured or guessed from a single picture?

Your question is extremely vague.  Some thoughts:

How to determine if something is horizontal or vertical?  See if the width is greater than the height.  If your object or images is 60x400, then you have a vertical object or image.  If it is 400x60, then you are looking at something horizontal.  If this is not what you meant, then post some examples so we can better understand your question.

I couldn't figure out why you posted an image of a transmission tower with your questions.  (You need to better explain what you are doing.)  Then I noticed you're likely detecting and/or counting the glass or porcelain insulation disks.  If you need to count the disks, once your network has identified each of the set of insulators as you show in that image, why not create a RoI to "crop" them, and feed it back into the neural network to count them?  In this example, my network would probably be sized as 320x640 to accommodate the aspect ratio of the RoI used to "crop" the insulators:




Make sure you understand how sizing works.  There are 3 sizes you need to track:  the size of the network, the size of the image, and the size of the objects within the image.  This is explained here:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#how_does_sizing_work  Once you understand how that works, then you can size your network correctly, as explained here:  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#optimal_network_size

I'm not sure what you mean or are trying to do about "distances".  The distance between the disks?  The distance between the sets of disks on a tower?  The distance between the camera and the bottom of the tower?  The distance between the ground and the top of the tower?  Again, please explain better, and post some several examples.

Join the YOLO discord server if you want help from other YOLO users:  https://discord.gg/zSq8rtW



"extremely vague" questions shouldn't be answered. OP should be supported (using comments) in clarifying the question, so that the question can be answered. several questions in an answer, asking for clarification, indicate strongly that the question isn't fit to answer, and should not be answered, and the answer isn't really an answer. -- good questions should be upvoted, vague ones not. I see a correlation between the question's upvote and your answer's creation. -- I believe this is outlined in [answer]

@stephane thank you 2nd and 3rd point really helps basically distance means i want to measure the insulator which one is longer and which is slightly shorter for many of the images these insulator disk is not visible and photos taken with different angles as well, so i cannot take a count of disk but i want to measure the length of the insulator
